# Rearranging dynamic arrays with es2015

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Im working with some data from the page to manipulate and re order an array. So far I have reordered my array of Objects, based on a serperate "sorting array" order. The original array was this:

```
[  
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"Cheap-Coilovers.co.uk",
      "providerName":"pricerunner",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"House of Fraser",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"notonthehighstreet.com",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   }
]
```

I then run this array through my sort function:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    let sortingArr = ['connexity', 'ecn', 'kelkoo', 'nexttag', 'pricerunner', 'shopping', 'ebay'];

    if (sortingArr.indexOf(a.providerName) < sortingArr.indexOf(b.providerName)) {
       return -1;
    }
    if (sortingArr.indexOf(a.providerName) > sortingArr.indexOf(b.providerName)) { 
       return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
retailersOrdered.sort(compare);
```

This then gives me my array of objects in the order of the sorting array which is great, and the desired effect:

```
[  
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"House of Fraser",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"notonthehighstreet.com",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"Cheap-Coilovers.co.uk",
      "providerName":"pricerunner",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "needProcessing":false
   }
]
```

I would now like to take this a step further and order the array in a sort of "round robin" fashion. So it takes the first object with providerName "connexity", then the first object with providerName "pricerunner", then the first object with providerName "ebay" and then back to the beginning, the second object with providerName "connexity" and so on. to give the desired output:

```
[  
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"House of Fraser",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"Cheap-Coilovers.co.uk",
      "providerName":"pricerunner",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"notonthehighstreet.com",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   }
]
```

This array is built up dynamically and with a varying number of objects per provider. Im struggling to come up with a way of sorting this array in order of provider[1], then provider[2] with dynamic names and lengths. Im hoping there is some new functionality of es2015 that could help achieve this? Any knowledge of ordering arrays in such a way would be great.

Comment: That's not a *sort*, because for a round-robin-layout you don't have a [comparable ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability).

Comment: What you can do is to create multiple arrays, one for each provider name. Traverse through your array and populate new arrays (one for each provider name). Now populate your original array by traversing through each array for provider name in order of their precedence

Comment: Just do `tags.map(t => retailers.filter(by(t))).transpose().flatten()` - but no, neither `by` nor `transpose` nor `flatten` are part of ES6. You can find many implementations on the web if you don't know what they do, though.

Comment: Check out my answer and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to stitch the arrays together one element at a time until all elements have been added in round robin order. This can be accomplished by creating an ordered list of the providerNames in use, grouping the items by providerName, and then pushing the correct element into a new array to be returned. Here's a demo:

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"Cheap-Coilovers.co.uk",
      "providerName":"pricerunner",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"House of Fraser",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   },
   {  
      "domain":"www.exampleurl.com/redirect",
      "retailerName":"notonthehighstreet.com",
      "providerName":"connexity",
      "needProcessing":false
   }
];

var providerNameIndex = 0;
// group objects by provider name
var groupedByProviderName = data.reduce(function (result, current) {
    if (!result[current.providerName]) {
        result[current.providerName] = [];
    }
    result[current.providerName].push(current);
    return result;
}, {});

// get providerNames in use, sorted in order specified by sortingArr
var providerNames = Object.keys(groupedByProviderName).sort(function (a, b) {
    let sortingArr = ['connexity', 'ecn', 'kelkoo', 'nexttag', 'pricerunner', 'shopping', 'ebay'];
    if (sortingArr.indexOf(a) < sortingArr.indexOf(b)) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (sortingArr.indexOf(a) > sortingArr.indexOf(b)) { 
      return 1;
    }
  return 0;
});

function stitch (obj) {
    var results = [];
    // repeat until all items have been placed in new array
    while(providerNames.some(name => obj[name].length)) {
        // cycle through provider names
        var providerName = providerNames[providerNameIndex % providerNames.length];
        // if array still has items, push first item into new arr
        if(obj[providerName].length) {
            results.push(obj[providerName].shift());
        }
        // increment index to get next provider name in sequence
        providerNameIndex++;
    }
    
    return results;
}

console.log(stitch(groupedByProviderName));
```